# What bet to make in this Texas Holdem Tournament?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I was playing in a tournament. About 115 players started each getting 5000 chips. There was about 45 players left and I had just been moved to a different table, I had 17000 in chips. The blinds were now 1000/2000. The second hand after I sat down I was the big blind and was dealt pocket Aces. One player bet 2000, all others including the small blind folded.

What bet should I make?

The player who bet 2000 had more chips than me but I'm not sure how much as I had just been moved to the table.

In the actual game, I raised to 5000 (an additional 3000). 
The other player called.
The flop was K, J, 7 all different suits.
I bet 2000, the other player called.
The turn was a 5, I bet another 2000. The other player raised another 3000. 
This left me with 5000 so I went in all. The other player called.
He showed K, 3 not suited.

My bad luck, the river card was a 3 and I was knocked out.

Should I have bet differently?
Should I have gone all in before the flop?

Comment: This is going to be totally opinion based.  There isn't a right or wrong answer here.

Comment: 2000 is a call, not a bet.

Comment: @StartPlayer, how is this opinion based?  The mathematics and strategy of Texas Hold'em is very deeply understood (just not by me).  Can you provide more evidence as to why you think this is opinion based?

Comment: @StartPlayer There exists an optimal mixed strategy. One can have opinions as to what it is, but what it is is a factual question (albeit one dependent on factors not included in the question).

Comment: Indeed, there are many factors of how many people are at the table, their chip counts, the blind structure (timing, mostly), any history of the players (which seems to be zero, if you just sat down). Any answer would be subjective, but not necessarily *opinion-based*. Checking accomplishes something. Betting 3-4x accomplishes something. Going all-in accomplishes something. I'd go all-in with 8.5 BB left, and hope to get in good pre-flop. But I just play once a year :)

Comment: @John Yes there is a lot of strategy once you have information on the players but when all you have is a chip count and your hold cards it doesn't give you much to go on.

Comment: @John.  I could provide you more evidence but it's all opinion based.  Personally I would have gone all in pre flop.   That might have changed depending if the other player only had me slightly covered.  So there isn't an answer.  ITs about what you want to to do in that situation at that time.  Like all games, it would be very boring if there was always 'the correct' thing to do all the time.

Comment: @john I think will be helpful to you is to avoid 'results oriented thinking'   It seems your smarting they hit the 3.  You could argue that you got your chips in whilst you were ahead. In which case you made the right decision.  If you went all in pre and they called AA is ahead of K3 so you would have made the right decision. If when you went all in on turn and they had KK you would have made wrong decision.  The fact is there is't going to always be a clear 'correct move' (so no answer)  unless you know all the cards.  In poker you can make right decision and get wrong result and vice versa.

Comment: This question seems familiar enough to me to many other well-received questions about good strategy for all sorts of various games.

Comment: For sure you bet too small on the flop.  That was time to jam.  But you probably would have been called anyway.  Not much you can do.

Comment: @StartPlayer - can you move your comments to an answer?  Your expertise here should lead to a good answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @PatLudwig I don't think what I said is an answer.  Its just an opinion based on years of playing Poker and Boardgames. I can't give solid reference for anything. My view applies to both,  there is very rarely a 'correct' play in games.  Players are free to make whatever choices they make depending on there objectives.  In view of the question there are so many unknown variables, the main being what was the players objective? trying to double up, trying to take some chips, trying to take blinds, trying to avoid losing with aces.  The only way I could answer this would be drawing a flow chart!

Comment: @StartPlayer - An opinion based on specific expertise is what we call an answer around here :)  Sharing your knowledge is what we live for!

Answer (score 3):

You had 8 big blinds. That is a spot to push pre flop (go all-in) out of position (OOP). You should be playing a wide range in that spot and could get called with a wide range. You win the bet that was placed and the small blind if the villain folds. Losing to K3 is unlucky but you need to gamble with a small stack and AA is a good hand to gamble with.

Comment: For the uninitiated: Please explain what "*at 8 bb*", "*is a cooler*" and "*pick up the bet and sb*"  mean.

Comment: Agree 100% with this opinion. It is a much better line. Added some edits to clarify some of the poker slang.

Answer (score 1):

With pocket aces, calling (not raising) is slow playing. It can work, because players with lower pairs or Ace King, or Ace rag (a low card) might play or raise instead of folding. If they raise, then I would have probably re-raised about 4 times the raise or at least the full pot before the flop as there is always the danger any low cards will make 2 pair, 3 of a kind or trips.

As a general rule never go all in with nothing, I would avoid it with one pair, even two pair is risky, unless you have more chips and will win a decent side pot if you lose. `K 3` was a terrible hand to call with and you were just unlucky. If it's any consolation, he must have had a dreadful night to call with it.